# Существует ли в данном предложении лексическая ошибка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

**В** **преддверии собрания нам нужно подготовить все необходимые бумажки.**

Comment: думаю да - *бумажки*.)

Comment: А стиль речи какой?

Comment: Орфографические словари фиксируют единственно возможную норму: в преддверии (в значении «перед каким-либо событием»). Исключений нет: предлог «в преддверии» всегда пишется с двумя «д» и с окончанием «ии».

Comment: а есть ли смысл обсуждать лексику в разговорном стиле?

Comment: Думаю, здесь не лексическая, а стилистическая ошибка. Разговорное "бумажки" не вписывается в предложение с официальным (пафосным, торжественным, книжным) "в преддверии".

Answer (score 1):

Между знакомыми и друзьями вполне можно и бумажки говорить. А если сомневаешься, обычно это с незнакомыми или плохо знакомыми или некоторыми знакомыми, но для делового стиля   лучше сказать  или писать **«документы»,** т.к. есть шанс что с той стороны могут возникнуть сомнения разного рода (например могут подумать о нашей несерьезности или усомниться в самих «бумажках»).

*Но в данном предложении  присутствует  стилистическая или лексическая ошибка.  Потому что грамотно ( с точки зрения стиля) надо было бы  написать так:*

В преддверии собрания нам нужно  подготовить все необходимые **документы.**

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы привести текст предложения к официальному стилю (который задает предлог ***«в преддверии»***) и при этом почти не отклониться от изначального текста, я бы заменил разговорное слово ***«бумажки»*** на более деловое слово ***«бумаги»***:

> **В преддверии собрания нам нужно подготовить все необходимые бумаги.**